# Windows Service not working properly when an exe converted to a service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

Production Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition
Development Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

I wanted to start an .exe at the system startup. I have created a windows service using .Net, which starts the exe on service start.

In Developmenet deployed the service and it is working fine.

1. Service Name: ExeStart
2. Display Name: ExeStart
3. Logon using – Local System Account
4. Startup Type: Automatic(Delay Start)

Deployed the same service to UAT server, where the service is showing running but not working as expected. In the task manager I can see that exe is running.

If the exe started manually, it is showing 7MB memory in task manager, while started from the service it is only showing 4MB memory.

Is there any dependencies failed while starting the service?? If so, how could I find out dependencies of this service.

This service is running, exe is showing running but not working. What could be the issue here?

Comment: anything in the eventlog?

Comment: check the service permissions, by default  all services runs under SYSTEM Account.. See the logs if have any

Comment: "not working as expected" - what does that mean? Could you describe that more properly?

Comment: @Aubis1233 - event log is updated with "Service started successfully".

Comment: @Rajesh - Service runned with Local System Account and Administrator account as well.

Comment: @Bernard -the service is like a SQL Server service, if it is running, users can able to log in to the application from the network. Users are not able to access the application from the network or from the Server.

Comment: Get some logs working. It could be as simple as a reference not existing but the error is handled during run-time. Service is working but not doing anything.